# Подсчёт повторяющихся знаечений

Tags: sql, sql-server

Присутствует следующая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE #main (id varchar(50));  
INSERT INTO #main VALUES
('93'),
('90'),
('32'),
('11'),
('11'),
('32'),
('32'); 
select * 
from #main
```

Подскажите, каким образом я могу приджойнить столбец, в котором будет подсчитываться кол-во одинаковых значений для каждого id?
Желаемый итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понимаю, но таким образом исходная таблица не сохраняется. Для моей задачи нужно оставить повторяющиеся id в том же виде, как на скрине.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) repeat
FROM #main
```